# Retrieve data ("notification" object) from default Firebase notification after click

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using Firebase messaging library 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

with basic, out-of-the box setup and extended `FirebaseMessagingService` and `FirebaseInstanceIdService`. I am able to receive notifications without any issues.

I am sending notification via API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Example message:

```
{
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "to": "<myDeviceToken>",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title of notification",
    "body": "Body of notification"
  }
}
```

The important part is that I would like to keep it this way (and not sending "data" object with notification as well, since they would be the same).

My requirement is that after clicking on the notification (hot or cold start, both should behave the same), the app will be opened on the main activity (I don't need to go to different activities).
Here I need to show a message box with the same information like it was shown in the notification.

My question is - how can I retrieve this "notification" object when a user clicked on the notification?

From documentation:

> Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In
>   this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
>   A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

This is exactly what I want and it works, the only thing I need more is that I want to get the data from "notification" object of that notification that was clicked on.

Comment: I would like to avoid 'click_action' in the payload as well - I would like to send the most basic notification payload possible and to have it the same for Android and iOS (for iOS this works well without any modifications - even for hot and cold starts).

Comment: @Tunex You need to when click in notification open the mainActivity and get the notification data right?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any solution to this without using data in the payload together with click_action. This is working. It's just that I don't like that solution because I need to send the data in the payload twice, which is not so effective.